# Sonarqube PostProjectAnalysisTask example?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have been searching for any PostProjectAnalysisTask working code example, with no look. [This](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Hooks) page states that [HipChat plugin](https://github.com/dbac2002/sonar-hipchat-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sonar/hipchat/plugin) uses this hook, but it seems to me that it still uses the legacy PostJob extension point ...

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on their page now.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Hooks

```
import org.sonar.api.ce.posttask.PostProjectAnalysisTask;
import org.sonar.api.server.Server;

public class MyHook implements PostProjectAnalysisTask {
  private final Server server;

  public MyHook(Server server) {
    this.server = server;
  }

  @Override
  public void finished(ProjectAnalysis analysis) {
    QualityGate gate = analysis.getQualityGate();
    if (gate.getStatus()== QualityGate.Status.ERROR) {
      String baseUrl = server.getURL();
      // TODO send notification
    }
  }
```